# Cannot Copy and Paste Sheet from one Workbook to Another

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, paste

I have a Workbook with a ton of VBA code that processes data from a report and breaks it down in a dashboard. I am trying to create a button that allows the user to browse for a new report to update the data set.

Essentially, I have a dashboard sheet and a report sheet in my workbook. When the user selects a new file, it should replace everything in the report sheet with the data from the file selected by the user.

The problem I am having is a "1004 - Paste Special Error" when the code goes to paste the data from the sheet selected by the user. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've been reading through posts here and elsewhere and have tried multiple ways of copying and pasting sheets, but so far nothing has worked.

I should note that in the code below I have:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

And I feel like the ".Range("A1")" is wrong, but if I don't specify a range Excel will just paste whatever I have in my clipboard instead of the contents of the workbook I selected.

My current code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Set DataSource = Worksheets("Report")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your Report", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*, *xls*")
    
   'Here I am clearing any filters applied to the sheet
    On Error Resume Next
        DataSource.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Then I delete the existing data
    DataSource.Cells.ClearContents
    
    'Then I try to copy and paste the data
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Copy
        'This line is where I keep encountering a Paste Special Error
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `OpenBook.Sheets(1).Copy` copies a worksheet object (not a worksheet's cells).  `.PasteSpecial` pastes cells (not a worksheet object). Unsure which it is you're trying to do (copy a worksheet or copy its data). But those two lines of code don't make sense like that and are why you're seeing that error (i.e. no cells have been copied).

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. That makes way more sense.

How should I copy the worksheet's cells? Do I have to specify a range?

Comment: Yes, you copy a range by specifying same and using `.Copy` which is one the Methods of a range).